# Updating a SPFieldMultiLineText field

Tags: list, development, splistitem, spfield

I have an SPListItem. I have a field on the item of type SPFieldMultiLineText. How can update the value of that field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the field value in HTML/Plain text format and update it. Here you go:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site")) 
{ 
         using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) 
         { 

           SPList list = web.Lists["YourList"]; 
           SPListItem item= list.GetItemById(1);
           SPFieldMultiLineText multilineField = item.Fields.GetField("YourColumn") as SPFieldMultiLineText;
           // Get the field value as HTML
           string htmltext= multilineField.GetFieldValueAsHtml(item["YourColumn"], item);

           //or Get the field as Text
           string normaltext= multilineField.GetFieldValueAsText(item["YourColumn"]); 

           //updating html field text
           htmltext+= "Hello I am being updated!";
           item["YourColumn"] = htmltext;
           item.Update();
         }
}
```